# widget to display related posts in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, widget, related-posts

I starting a blog where I have this structure for my posts: for each post published in the category MAIN, i have 3-4 others posts in the categories A,B,C... which are related to the former.

I want add a widget to display the post of the categories A,B,C..., this way:

- if the  widget is displayed in the start page, the posts related to more recent post published in the category MAIN are listed;
- if the widget is displayed in the post page, the posts related to this post are listed.

anyone knows how to accomplish that? where I should put the code for this widget? what wordpress variables are used?

Comment: Check out [YARPP](https://wordpress.org/plugins/yet-another-related-posts-plugin/) that may need some tweaking but should do the job.

Comment: @ScottMcGready I know about the YARPP, but this don't work for me, because the relation between the post here it's just the publish date (the post in categories MAIN, A, B, C... are all published in the same day). The YARPP, I guess, group the post by tags or something similar.